# jquery $(function () is not working on Web UI

Tags: jquery

I am a new bee in jquery and trying to find out what's going wrong with my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#BtnSubmit").click(function () {
        alert(" I am here"); 
        $("#BtnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        $("#BtnCancel").attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass("ui-state-disabled");
    });
    });
</script>
```

Not even showing the aler msg. Though the same code is working in another page as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#BtnSubmit").click(function () {
            alert(" I am here"); 
            $("#BtnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
            $("#BtnCancel").attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass("ui-state-disabled");
    });     
    });
</script>
```

What's going wrong here? Can anybody help?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code => we will need more information / code.

Comment: Is it possible you have multiple elements with the id of `BtnSubmit`?

Comment: Just as a side note, you can use `$("#BtnSubmit, #BtnCancel").attr(...` to do the same thing with both elements in a single statement

Comment: Please show us the corresponding HTML that goes with this as there's nothing obviously wrong with the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Is your content generated dynamically? If so, try using `.live` rather than `.click`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // $("#BtnSubmit").click(function () {
        $("#BtnSubmit").live('click', function () {
            alert(" I am here"); 
            $("#BtnSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
            $("#BtnCancel").attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        });

    });
</script>
```